# Weird characters in ASP.Net (C#) URL link stops Request.QueryString processes

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, request.querystring

I created a page in my web application that allows the user to change the account's e-mail address. To do so there is a form to complete and then a verification link is sent to the current email, the user clicks it and then another e-mail goes to the new e-mail. The problem is that from Outlook service, the link appears as:

```
webapp.com/page?blabla¤t_email=blabla
```

instead of:

```
webapp.com/page?blabla&current_email=blabla
```

This causes the Request.QueryString to read the URl wrong and the page to crash... Any ideas please?

This is the code I'm using to create the link:

```
string mailtransfer = "http://localhost:53631/Account/Transfer.aspx?username=" + username + "&current_email=" + mail0.Text + "&new_email=" + mail1.Text + "&web_aktiviert=" + finalString + "&transfer_proccess=1";
```

finalString is the 11 numeric string created. transfer_proccess is the steps for the Request.QueryString to load the appropriate page. The problem happens at the &current_email (it replaces the "&curren" with "¤")
This is not a replacement of characters with their html encoding - the symbol always replaces the specific characters

Comment: Show the code you are using to make the verification link.